# Is it possible to count the number of times each key has occurred in a column of JSON?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with a single column which has JSON in it.

I would like to output the count of the number of times each key appears in the column, and then sort by counts in descending order. The values associated with all of the keys are `1`.

There is a known / finite number of keys per object, but I'd rather not rely on it in case the largest object seen changes.

There is a known / finite number of keys overall, but I'd like to not rely on enumerating / updating a list as it changes.

e.g. input: three rows, one column named "json"

```
[
  {"json": "{'A': 1}"},
  {"json": "{'B': 1}"},
  {"json": "{'B': 1, 'C': 1}"}
]
```

e.g. output: three rows, two columns named "key" and "count"

```
[
  {"key": "B", "count": 2},
  {"key": "A", "count": 1},
  {"key": "C", "count": 1}
]
```

What's the simplest way of doing this, given that I don't want to rely on the finite number of keys per object and overall?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  At least provide some simple example showing your input data and expected result. That would be the ultimate minimum I think

Comment: (I have relatively gross working code that relies on the finite number of keys per object and finite number of keys overall, but cannot think of a way of doing this without these constraints)

Comment: clarify  - your input example represent three rows or it is one row

Comment: both input and output are three rows, although it's a coincidence that that number matches up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable Legacy SQL, you can make use of the new bigquery REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL function, which appears to be exactly what you're looking for: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract_all

Comment: As for getting the query into Mode, I would suggest doing the non-legacy sql as a view in bigquery. Mode should be able to query the view without an issue.

Answer (score 4):

> below for BigQuery Standard SQL

see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) and [User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION parseJson(y STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var z = new Array();
  processKey(JSON.parse(y), '');
  function processKey(node, parent) {
    Object.keys(node).map(function(key) {
      value = node[key].toString();
      if (value !== '[object Object]') {
        z.push(key)
      } else {
        if (parent !== '' && parent.substr(parent.length-1) !== '.') {parent += '.'};
        processKey(node[key], parent + key);
      };
    });         
  };
  return z
""";

WITH theTable AS (
  SELECT '{"json":{"A":"1"}}' AS json UNION ALL 
  SELECT '{"json":{"B":"1"}}' AS json UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"json":{"B":"1","C":"1"}}' AS json
)
SELECT key, COUNT(1) AS `count`
FROM theTable, UNNEST(parseJson(json)) AS key
GROUP BY key
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

output:

```
key count    
B       2    
A       1    
C       1
```

Note: parseJson UDF is generic enough to handle any json, so you can for example try above code with below input and it still will work:

```
WITH theTable AS (
  SELECT '{"json":{"A":"1"}}' AS json UNION ALL 
  SELECT '{"json":{"B":"1"}}' AS json UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"json":{"B":"1","C":"1"}}' AS json UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"A":"1"}' AS json UNION ALL 
  SELECT '{"B":"1"}' AS json UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"B":"1","C":"1"}' AS json
```

)

output:

```
key count    
B       4    
A       2    
C       2
```

> Added version for BigQuery Legacy SQL

For the sake of simplicity of presenting here and further testing - i am using here `inline version` of Legacy SQL UDF. `Inline version` in Legacy SQL is not officially supported - so if it works for you - you will need to slightly transform it - see [BigQuery User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) for details about UDF in BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT key, COUNT(1) as cnt
FROM JS((
  SELECT json FROM  
    (SELECT '{"json":{"A":"1"}}' AS json),
    (SELECT '{"json":{"B":"1"}}' AS json),
    (SELECT '{"json":{"B":"1","C":"1"}}' AS json),
    (SELECT '{"A":"1"}' AS json),
    (SELECT '{"B":"1"}' AS json),
    (SELECT '{"B":"1","C":"1"}' AS json)
  ),
  json,                                    // Input columns
  "[{name: 'parent', type:'string'},       // Output schema
   {name: 'key', type:'string'},
   {name: 'value', type:'string'}]",
   "function(r, emit) {                    // The function
      processKey(JSON.parse(r.json), '');
      function processKey(node, parent) {
        Object.keys(node).map(function(key) {
          value = node[key].toString();
          if (value !== '[object Object]') {
            emit({parent:parent, key:key, value:value});
          } else {
            if (parent !== '' && parent.substr(parent.length-1) !== '.') {parent += '.'};
            processKey(node[key], parent + key);
          };
        });         
      };
    }"
  )
GROUP BY key
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this is for a Mode Analytics dashboard, which does not support Standard SQL yet. I'll accept your answer if there are no Legacy SQL solutions within a week.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov - just added version for bigquery legacy sql

Comment: You may be able to use standard SQL with the dashboard by putting `#StandardSQL` on the first line of the query (depending on whether the dashboard modifies the text before sending it to BigQuery).