# How do I extract all JSON values from all keys in SQL Bigquery?

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a json string in bigquery that looks like that:

`{"1":"eggs","2":"nuts","3":"fish"}`

How could I extract all values without listing the keys? What I need is:

`['eggs', 'nuts', 'fish']`

I've tried `[json_extract(json_string, '$[1]'), json_extract(json_string, '$[2]')]` and it does the job but it won't work if the number of keys increases

Comment: You're probably going to have to implement your own function, such as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59490036/53341 *(Also, find whomever supplied you a dictionary/object instead of a list/array, and shoot them.)*

Comment: Using that custom function I'm able to get all distinct keys, but I'm not sure how could I use it to get the values?

Comment: Change the function to return values instead of keys, or use the keys as an input to JSON_EXTRACT().

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using this query:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jsonObjectValues(input STRING)
RETURNS Array<String>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  RETURN Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
""";

SELECT
  jsonObjectValues(value) AS values
FROM my_dataset
```