# UDF that accepts an arbitrary struct

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking for a custom function that can accept a `STRUCT` and return some string output of it. For this example, let us just assume the types of the struct may be a `STRING`, `INT64`, or a `DATE`. So we have something like this:

```
STRUCT(1 AS num, "hi" as str, DATE "2014-01-01" as date)
```

And in the output I would like to produce the following JSON obj, which is a list of triples -- `[key, value, type]`, with the `value` being the json-encoded value.

```
[
    ["num", 1, "INT64"],
    ["str", "hi", "STRING"],
    ["date", "2014-01-01", "DATE"]
]
```

How could I do this in BigQuery? So far I have some scaffolding down, but not quite sure how to get the "inspect" for the type or key of a value.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION structFunc(obj ANY TYPE)
RETURNS json
AS (
  JSON "[]"
);

SELECT
  structFunc(STRUCT(1 as num,"x" as str, date "2014-01-01" as date))
```

I'm hoping there is something like a `FOR` loop I can iterate over the k-v pairs.

---

Note, here is a related question -- [How to extract all the keys in a JSON object with BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890339/how-to-extract-all-the-keys-in-a-json-object-with-bigquery), that shows how to get an arbitrary list of k,v pairs in a `js` udf. However, it has the following two limitations:

1. JS requires an input type. It cannot allow `ANY TYPE`, and you do you not know the struct beforehand.
2. If you convert to json you lose non-json types unless you preserve additional information someplace else. For example `DATE "2014-01-01"` and `"2014-01-01"` would both be encoded the same in JSON even if they are two different types.

---

Additionally, if this is an easier way to solve this. I am fine having the `STRUCT` as part of a stored table if it inspecting the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` makes this simpler to solve. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `my-dataset.123`.tbl AS (
    SELECT STRUCT(1 as num,"x" as str, date "2014-01-01" as date) as val
)
```

In this way perhaps we could create a js udf that has a signature something like this:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION structFunc(obj ANY TYPE)
RETURNS json
LANGUAGE js
AS r"""
    function toTriples(
        obj_as_json:JSON, 
        metadata_from_information_schema:JSON
    ) {...}
""";
```

And here are two additional helpers to get the **value** as well as the **info** :

```
-- CREATE TABLE `my-dataset.123`.tbl AS (SELECT STRUCT(1 as num,"x" as str, date "2014-01-01" as date) as val);

-- Get the value
select to_json(val) from `my-dataset.123`.tbl

-- Get the info (array<field_path STRING, data_type STRING>)
select array(SELECT as struct
  field_path, data_type
FROM
  `my-dataset.123`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS
WHERE
  table_name = 'tbl'
  AND column_name = 'val')
```

Comment: Sorry the answer was messed up. Deleted.

Comment: @MehmetKaplan -- I see, how were you able to enter in that function in BQ? Or was it another product or something? I was so excited when I saw your answer, I didn't think that was possible in BQ...